# find data and paste all matching data in separate lists VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a search function which is like control F but with a few tweaks. The data which i am matching to has the file location of said data in the cell to the left of it. The goal is to find any matching data and pull the file location from the cell next to it, then put it in a list on a separate worksheet. I'm currently trying to get it to work for just one sheet, then replicate for the rest.

I've tried various different codes and looked at different solutions on here already, but nothing seems to work. when i run my code, it runs but nothing happens and I'm not sure why.

```
Sub TEST()

Dim Shtf As Worksheet
Dim ShtTDO As Worksheet
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim filematch As Range
Dim destcell As Range
Dim firstfilematch As String
Dim filename As String
Dim CountInTDO As Long

Set Shtf = Sheet5
        filename = Sheet5.Cells(6, 2).Value
Set ShtTDO = Sheet2
    
        
        'finds matching filename witin TDO sheet
 With ShtTDO.Range("B:B")
                Set filematch = .Find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not filematch Is Nothing Then
                    firstfilematch = filematch.Address
                    Do
                        'Copies the correct cell and pastes in a list
                        Set destcell = Shtf.Cells(12, 4)
                        filematch.Copy
                        Shtf.Paste Destination:=destcell
                        Set destcell = destcell.Offset(1)
                        Set filematch = .FindNext(filematch)
                    Loop While Not filematch Is Nothing And filematch.Address <> firstfilematch
                End If
            End With
        
End Sub
```

| File location | File name |
| --- | --- |
| Location1 | File1 |
| Location2 | File2 |
| Location3 | File3 |

Comment: Please post a sample of your data (inputs and expected outputs). I recommend https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Also please step through the code line-by-line using <kbd>F8</kbd> and let us know which line of the code isn't doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Hi @SpencerBarnes, I've added a table to show what my data looks like. Unfortunately my problem is that it doesn't have an error, it just doesn't do anything, so I can't say where the error is.

Comment: I didn't ask for an error, I asked which line isn't doing what you expect it to. If nothing at all is happening, perhaps `filematch Is Nothing` causing it to skip the action part of the code?

Comment: One fairly obvious bug, `destcell` is being set to `ShtF.cells(12,4)` at the start of every single loop. To start at that cell and then iterate on from it, move the first `Set descell =` line to before the `Do`

Comment: I removed the `filematch is nothing` and it now gives a 1004 error (application defined or object defined error). i also found it gives this error if the input perfectly matches the data in the other sheet. without removing the `filematch is nothing`

Comment: I also moved the `destcell` to outside the first `do` as suggested thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The code i was using was fine, i just had to change the `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`. Also, merged cells was an issue! i didn't know they would make it stop working. i unmerged them and the code was fine. Final Code below.

```
    Sub Search()

Range("D15:I1000").Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'define variables
Dim Shtf As Worksheet
Dim ShtTDO As Worksheet
Dim ShtIMF As Worksheet
Dim ShtCAD As Worksheet
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim filematch As Range
Dim destcell As Range
Dim firstfilematch As String
Dim filename As String
Dim CountInTDO As Long

'set variables
Set Shtf = Sheet5
        filename = Sheet5.Cells(6, 2).Value
Set ShtTDO = Sheet2
Set ShtCAD = Sheet1
Set ShtIMF = Sheet3
        
        'finds matching filename witin TDO sheet
With ShtIMF.Range("B:B")
 Set filematch = .Find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not filematch Is Nothing Then
        firstfilematch = filematch.Address
        Set destcell = Shtf.Cells(15, 4)
        Do
            'Copies the correct cell and pastes in a list
            filematch.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
            Shtf.Paste Destination:=destcell
            Set destcell = destcell.Offset(1)
            Set filematch = .FindNext(filematch)
        Loop While Not filematch Is Nothing And filematch.Address <> firstfilematch
    End If
End With
            
With ShtTDO.Range("B:B")
 Set filematch = .Find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not filematch Is Nothing Then
        firstfilematch = filematch.Address
        Set destcell = Shtf.Cells(15, 6)
        Do
            'Copies the correct cell and pastes in a list
            filematch.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
            Shtf.Paste Destination:=destcell
            Set destcell = destcell.Offset(1)
            Set filematch = .FindNext(filematch)
        Loop While Not filematch Is Nothing And filematch.Address <> firstfilematch
    End If
End With

With ShtCAD.Range("B:B")
 Set filematch = .Find(filename, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not filematch Is Nothing Then
        firstfilematch = filematch.Address
        Set destcell = Shtf.Cells(15, 8)
        Do
            'Copies the correct cell and pastes in a list
            filematch.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
            Shtf.Paste Destination:=destcell
            Set destcell = destcell.Offset(1)
            Set filematch = .FindNext(filematch)
        Loop While Not filematch Is Nothing And filematch.Address <> firstfilematch
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```